# Carregar uma página após preenchimento de um textfield usando jQuery

Tags: jquery

Estou fazendo um jogo de Jokenpo, e preciso de um nome de usuário para colocar no Score. No caso criei uma página inicial com um textfield para o usuário digitar o seu nome. Logo após ter digitado o seu nome, deve abrir a outra página onde está o jogo com as opções.

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="nameJogador" placeholder="Nome do Jogador">

</div> 


$(document).ready(function(){

$("#nameJogador").focusout(function(){
    var nomeJogador = $("#nameJogador").val();
    //$("input#nameJogador").load('index_game');
    alert(nomeJogador);
    });


});
```

Comment: O que exatamente você não está conseguindo fazer?

Comment: Tipo eu fiz o evento, Só que eu queria que depois que perde o foco, a variável nomeJogador pegasse o valor do TxField, abrisse a outra página onde tá o jogo em si e o script do JS pegasse esse valor dessa primeira página para fazer as comparações.

Comment: Coloquei uma resposta, vê se é isso que você quer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi bem, você pode usar `localStorage` para armazenar o nome digitado na pagina anterior, ex:

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="nameJogador" placeholder="Nome do Jogador">
</div> 


$("#nameJogador").focusout(function(){
    var nomeJogador = $(this).val()
    localStorage.setItem('jogador', nomeJogador)

    window.location.href = 'outraPAgina' 
});
```

Feito isso você já foi para o outra pagina e tem o nome do jogador armazenado em `localStorage`, agora basta recuperar (quando necessario).

```
$('#score').text('O nome do jogador é: ' + localStorage.jogador)
```

Comment: Exatamente isso mano, muito obrigado! Ficou perfeito, agradecido pelo seu tempo!

Comment: @Vinicius1402 Caso tenha resolvido, marcar como `resolvido`, clicando no icone de `check` ao lado da pergunta.